# In substitution, what is the word for the expression substituted in and the pattern replaced?

Tags: logic, terminology, substitution

This is just a question about terminology.

As part of a project in a mathematical logic course, I'm working through parts of Whitehead & Russell's *Principia Mathematica*. W & R use quite a neat notation to explain the substitutions they use to explore consequences of the axioms in the formal theory they present:

$$\left[\text{axiom}\frac{a}{b}\right]$$

where *axiom* is the name of the axiom being used, $a$ is *the expression being introduced*, and $b$ is *the pattern in the axiom that is being replaced*.

For example, the substitution $\displaystyle\left[\text{Taut}\frac{\sim p}{p}\right]$ means to replace $p$ with $\sim p$ in the axiom "Taut", which is $p\lor p\;.\supset.\; p$, to give us $\sim p\;\lor \sim p\;.\supset.\; \sim p$.

What is the correct word for *the expression being introduced*, and *the pattern in the axiom that is being replaced*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, what is stated in the question as "the expression being introduced" is called *substitution instance* and that stated as "the pattern in the axiom that is being replaced" is called *propositional form*.

It should be remarked that

- In many presentations of logical systems, this distinction is deemed as somewhat pedantic and it is not marked at all.
- There is a fine distinction between *substitution* and *replacement*, usually overlooked, but worth being noted. Briefly to state:

We *replace* X with Y which is of the same kind as X. For example, we replace one proposition with another proposition.

We *substitute* X with Y which is not of the same kind of X. For example, we substitute a variable $x$ with a constant $c$.

Comment: Thanks for the response — that's great information, especially the distinction between *substitution* and *replacement*. Would you be able to include a reference to a work that uses the terms *instance* and *form*?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Paprzycka's [Substitution Instances](http://kpaprzycka.wdfiles.com/local--files/logic/W09) is quite explanatory. See [Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)) and [Propositional formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_formula) in Wikipedia (take "formula" as "form"). In case of axioms, "axiom schema" is used with the same idea. See [Schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/) in SEoP and [Axiom schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema) in Wikipedia. The terminology is not perfectly uniform, but do not mind this much.